# Highcharts - Possible to change the text zoom to other wording?

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to change the "Zoom" text in Highcharts to a custom text?

Comment: What do you mean by 'worlding'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setOptions to apply a [lang](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang) parameter.

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
   lang:{
      resetZoom: 'your own text',
      resetZoomTitle: 'your own zoom title'
   }
});
```